# Clear input field after button clicked

Tags: reactjs, forms

I'm building a simple task list in react and stuck with clearing the input field after the button is pushed and help would be appreciated. I have inspected it with the react extension and it is adding the value to my desired list and resting the curVal, but the input box is staying the same

```js
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    taskList: [],
    curValue: ""
  };

  changeHandler = event => {
    this.setState({ curValue: event.target.value });
  };

  newTaskHandler = () => {
    const itemValue = this.state.curValue;
    const clearInput = "";
    this.setState({
      taskList: [...this.state.taskList, itemValue],
      curValue: ""
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Task List</h1>
        <TaskInput
          click={this.newTaskHandler}
          value={this.state.curValue}
          changed={this.changeHandler}
        />

        <h1>{this.curValue}</h1>
        <h1>{this.taskList}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const TaskInput = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        name="task"
        value={props.curValue}
        onChange={props.changed}
      />
      <button type="submit" onClick={props.click}>
        Add to your Task List{" "}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The prop you give to your `TaskInput` is named `value`, not `curValue`.

Change `props.curValue` to `props.value` and it will work as expected.

```js
const TaskInput = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        name="task"
        value={props.value}
        onChange={props.changed}
      />
      <button type="submit" onClick={props.click}>
        Add to your Task List
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    taskList: [],
    curValue: ""
  };

  changeHandler = event => {
    this.setState({ curValue: event.target.value });
  };

  newTaskHandler = () => {
    const itemValue = this.state.curValue;
    const clearInput = "";
    this.setState({
      taskList: [...this.state.taskList, itemValue],
      curValue: ""
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Task List</h1>
        <TaskInput
          click={this.newTaskHandler}
          value={this.state.curValue}
          changed={this.changeHandler}
        />

        <h1>{this.curValue}</h1>
        <h1>{this.taskList}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const TaskInput = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        name="task"
        value={props.value}
        onChange={props.changed}
      />
      <button type="submit" onClick={props.click}>
        Add to your Task List
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: @Kyle Consider [accepting the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#answer-5235) if you feel it answered your question.